# webpack + javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack

Situacion:
Al intentar hacer un new de una función javascript, da error si el archivo fue compilado con webpack.

**Caso de uso donde si funciona (no pasa por webpack)
Archivo SiteController.js:**

```
var SiteController=function() {
};
```

Ejecucion dentro del body de mi página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
                new SiteController();
});
</script>
```

**Caso de uso donde no funciona, pasando los archivos javascript por webpack:**

*El archivo javascript luego de ser compilado por webpack, bundle_js_app.js:*

```
eval("\r\nvar SiteController=function() {\r\n\t\r\n};\r\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./resources/assets/frontend/js/bin/siteController.js?");
```

La ejecucion en la pagina sigue igual:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
                new SiteController();
});
</script>
```

El error:

> (index):205 Uncaught ReferenceError: SiteController is not defined
>       at (index):205

No se si debo hacer el new de una forma diferente o donde puede estar la solucion

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el HTML de la página donde lo estás probando?

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que el archivo `bundle_js_app.js` esta siendo cargado correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el orden en el que has puesto los scripts en tu página sea el incorrecto, porque aquí puedes ver que no hay problema en usar el código generado:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
eval("\r\nvar SiteController=function() {\r\n\tconsole.log('Hola Mundo');\r\n};\r\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./resources/assets/frontend/js/bin/siteController.js?");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
            new SiteController();
});
</script>
```